# Resize image when control is resized c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have just recently started developing Windows Form Controls, and one of the controls i am currently working on is simply (for now) a picturebox with an image. But i want the user of my control to be able to rezise the image. I have tried binding the control.resize event, but it didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: How do you want them to be able to resize the image?  Dragging with the mouse?  Does the image only need to resize when the form resizes?  (that would be easiest)

Comment: Change the Anchor property, also anchor the right and bottom.  Resizing the form now also resizes the control.

Comment: @Justin It needs to resize either when the control is resized, or maybe it is easier just setting a property imgSize, they can change.

Comment: I think you want to be able to control the position and size of the image in the picture box. Please be specific on what exactly you are trying to do. The way the question is worded it can be interpreted many ways. Can you show an example?

Comment: I am making a control that you can use in any project later on. I want to be able to resize it, like you can with a button. But i can't seem to get the picturebox or the image to resize..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the SizeMode property. More at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx

Comment: This dosen't seem to fix the problem. My image is stil the same size.

Comment: Just saw that i can resize the picturebox when editing the control itself, but i want the user to be able to resize it.

Comment: Does the picturebox get resized when you resize the control? If no - set anchors so that it does. The image will be resized with the containing control.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Resize += Form1_Resize;
}

void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Size = new Size(Width / 2, Height / 2);
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to happen when the form resizes, but when my control is resized. I have tried binding control.Resize, but that didn't seem to do the trick